# how do i resolve my error? (output "None")

Tags: python, python-3.x, fibonacci

I have written some code to output the fibonacci sequence up two the eighth  term:

```
def fibonacci():
    a=1
    b=1
    print (a)
    print (b)
    for i in range(0,8):
        current= a+b
        print (current)
        a=b
        b=current
```

It works but my output has the word None on the end, why am i getting this error?

```
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
None
```

I make it output 1, 1 so my sequence doesn't start at 2

Comment: Are you calling this like `print(fibonacci())` perhaps?

Comment: Remove the `8` in your function signature, it is not doing anything.

Comment: the 8 makes my sequence output 8 numbers

Comment: The `8` in `def fibonacci(8)` does nothing.

Comment: oops my mistake in entering it here i had 'n' there and user input which was assigned 'n'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you're calling the function like this:

```
print(fibonacci(8))
```

If you are, remove the `print()`:

```
fibonacci(8)
```